# Pipeline in Rails 3.2 not sending scss file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

We have two boxes, one of them runs the production environment against a dummy database. When we deploy to this box the file

```
app/assets/stylesheets/new_site.css.sccs
```

Is compiled and cached somewhere (as in it never appears in public/assets). It's referenced with

```
stylesheet_link_tag "new_site.css"
```

In the application template. It's served up fine.

I deliberately put an error in the file and both boxes failed - so I know it's compiling the file.

Our shiny new production box is compiling the file ok but not cacheing or serving it.

Having hacked around in the debugger a while I can't work out where to start debugging this. It seems to create the reference and everything but not put it in memcached - everything else is working fine.

If someone can give me a few other things to try I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we rewrote to use the pipeline as-is and ditched scss. Things it may be:

1. We use the Dalli gem - it might be doing something different (but versions controlled by Bundler)

Had a theory that it might be versions of memcached but both machines running same version 1.4.14

This is a weird one. Looking forward to starting cleanly with 4.2 next year.